# How do I replace the default IControllerFactory with my own implementation in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-core

I want to create my own implementation of IControllerFactory and IActionInvoker in an ASP.NET core application. How do I replace the default implementation with my custom class?

I found the solution for older versions of MVC `ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory` but cannot find a way to do that in ASP.NET core.

I believe I should configure this somewhere in Startup => ConfigureServices

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution by calling

```
services.AddSingleton<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.IControllerFactory, MyOwnImplementationClassOfControllerFactory>();
```

right before calling `services.AddMvc();`
where `MyOwnImplementationClassOfControllerFactory` is the custom implementation of IControllerFactory that is derived form `DefaultControllerFactory`.

I used singleton, because I found that the [default implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/48546dbb28ee762014f49caf052dc9c8a01eec3a/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/DependencyInjection/MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.cs) uses the following call `services.TryAddSingleton<IControllerFactory, DefaultControllerFactory>();`